# SlidingDrawer And ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, slidingdrawer

I have a SlidingDrawer. And I want use ScrollView in my SlidingDrawer. I Try but app is not running.

I am tried ScrollView in LinearLayout but still not running app.

How can I do this.

Here İs Code:

```
.
.
.
.
.
.

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SlidingDrawer
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="330dp"
            android:content="@+id/content"
            android:handle="@+id/handle"
            android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dip">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:text="==  ÇÖZÜM  =="
                android:textSize="10dp"/>

        <!-- I Try Add LinearLayout here But still not ronning.-->

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ababab"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:padding="10dip">
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    </ScrollView>
        </SlidingDrawer>
    </LinearLayout>
```

THANKS!

Comment: Remove your linear layout and set bottom to slidngdrawer and try once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my layout design that i had used in one of my project and it worked perfect check this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.wholesaleraja.touch_image.TouchImageZoom
            android:id="@+id/singe_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/raja" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/det"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/single_item_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Single Name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/single_item_text"
                android:background="@color/list_divider" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/code"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Product Code : "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/code_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/price_tag"
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/price_button_background"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:rotation="0" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/slideButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/up" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#e5e5e5" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="7dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Lot Size : "
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lot_size"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="1 "
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Piece(s)/Lot"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/details"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/list_divider"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:stretchColumns="*" >

                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/row3"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Lot(s) "
                                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Discount"
                                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Price/Lot"
                                    android:textSize="22sp" />
                            </TableRow>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:background="@color/list_divider" />
                        </TableLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp" >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Lot Qty : "
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minus"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number" >
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plus"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/addtocart"
                        style="@style/button_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cart_button_background"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Add to Cart"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/list_divider" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:text="Description"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
                        android:background="@color/list_divider" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/full_desc"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"

                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </SlidingDrawer>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```